# Drawing 3 rhombuses above each other

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

Here is the figure I wanna draw:

a big rhombus $\rightarrow$ 3 smaller rhombuses above each other and attached to each other.

Any help in that drawing will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[sep = large,
    /tikz/rhombus/.style={shape=diamond,draw,minimum size=3em}]
 |[rhombus,draw]|{}\arrow[r] & 
 |[rhombus,append after command={\pgfextra{\let\myln\tikzlastnode}
 (\myln.north) node[anchor=south,rhombus] {}
 (\myln.south) node[anchor=north,rhombus] {}}]|{}\\
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can control the size of the rhombi with the `minimum size` key, and the length of the arrow with `sep` and `shorten` keys.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[sep = 2em,
    /tikz/rhombus/.style={shape=diamond,draw,minimum size=2em}]
 |[rhombus,draw,minimum size=3em]|{}\arrow[r,shorten >=0.5em,shorten <=0.5em] & 
 |[rhombus,append after command={\pgfextra{\let\myln\tikzlastnode}
 (\myln.north) node[anchor=south,rhombus] {}
 (\myln.south) node[anchor=north,rhombus] {}}]|{}\\
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can the arrow be smaller than this?

Comment: Can the 3 rhombuses be smaller compared to the first one?

Comment: @Happy Yes, I added a second version and instructions for the keys that you can change.

Comment: Thank you so much :)